# Grid View header and row size are big when there are few records, when there are more rows it is fine

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view, the problem I am facing is when there is only 1 row in the table the header and the only row is really big, when the number of rows increases then the size of whole table and the header shrinks and it looks good, when there is few records it is looks like this

!http://www.freeimagehosting.net/43572

What is the problem here. thanks

```
   <asp:GridView ID="Grid_Messagetable" runat="server" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="5"
                        CssClass="Grid_MsgTbl" CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1" AllowPaging="False" SelectedIndex="0"
                        DataKeyNames="MsgID" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" OnRowDeleting="Grid_Messagetable_RowDeleting"
                        OnRowDataBound="MyGrid_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="true"
                        OnSorting="gridView_Sorting">



.Grid_MsgTbl
        {
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 1;
            left: 7px;
            top: 5px;
            position: relative;
            height: 308px;
            width: 646px; 
            right: 17px; 
            bottom: 524px;
        }
```

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/43572

Comment: Don't set height of rows and Gridview explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add more styles to your `css`.
Add `<HeaderStyle Height="30px"/>`

Also add   `AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="altrowstyle" and  HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerstyle"`

so you can add something like this to your `css`

```
.rowstyle td, .altrowstyle td {height:something}
```

But setting the height for the `gridview`not a good way of doing it since `.net` is clever enough to adjest the height accoding to data.

Anyway I think this article about [ASP.NET GridView makeover using CSS](http://atashbahar.com/post/GridView-makeover-using-CSS.aspx) will give you better idea.

Hope this helps

Comment: HeaderStyle Height="30px"/ solved the header size but the row size is the same after adding the alternating row style. how can I make it the same

Answer (score 0):

Never used `gridView` in `asp.net` but my guess is: Its size is being adjusted for the amount of data stored inside. You could try to set size for each element of the site by css. Also, if you have problems debugging the look of the site i recommend you getting [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) addon to `firefox`. It will really help you find out whats going out with your elements and which css transformations concern them.